# MacBookAirからSSHに接続しようとすると ”ssh: connect to host hostname port 22: Operation timed out” となる

Tags: macos, ssh

タイトルの通りMacBookAir(Mojave)からsshでサーバにアクセスしようとすると
"Operation timed out" となり接続できません．

同じネットワークでUbuntuからアクセスしてみた結果，通常通りアクセスすることができました．

```
$ ssh -v -i .ssh/key myname@myserver.tld
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myname/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myserver.tld port 22.
ssh: connect to host myserver.tld port 22: Operation timed out
```

研究室のサーバと私が契約しているVPSの両方にMacから接続できません。
Ubuntuからは両方ともアクセスできます。
解決策を教えていただければ幸いです．

Comment: 変な症状ですね…。正常につながってるUbuntu側の`ssh -v`との差異を比べてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 状況が漠然としていて答えにくいです。SSHサーバーのIPアドレスは正しく名前解決されているか、MacBook Air のネットワーク設定（DHCP/static, ルーターIP, DNS, …）、セキュリティーソフトの類、などを確認してください